# Trim the video to 5 minutes

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I am working on a demo project on which I have to get only 5 minutes video is there any way to trim the video to 5 minutes only. Currently, I am using FFmpeg flutter to get the video file and its metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following command code to split a video.

```dart
final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();   

_flutterFFmpeg
  .execute(
    '-i videoplayback.mp4 -ss 00:00:50 -t 00:01:30 -c copy smallfile1.mp4')
  .then((value) {
    print('Got value ');
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('Error');
  });
```

Start time is `-ss 00:00:50` end time is `00:01:30`

Comment: FFmpeg is taking too long for getting metadata of video like 25seconds for 6 minutes video is there any way to cut short this time

Answer (score 2):

You can use any `ffmpeg` command in `execute()` method of [flutter-ffmpeg package](https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg), to trim first 5 minutes of video

```
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';
....

final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
_flutterFFmpeg.execute("-ss 00:00:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:05:00 -c copy output.mp4").then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Comment: FFmpeg is taking too long for getting metadata of video like 25seconds for 6 minutes video is there any way to cut short this time.

Comment: when i run my flutter project i got the error from my pod file
```
    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of Hash into String.

     #  from /Volumes/Data/backup/We_Begins/We_Begins_With_Me/ios/Podfile:69
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #     plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
     >       symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
     #       File.symlink(path, symlink)
     #  -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @ParthBhanderi it is related to `CocoaPods`, could you show complete error log

Comment: thanks for reply i post my error log in answer bloc.

Comment: can you give me example how to use this plugin and what is the input.mp4 and output.mp4

Answer (score 1):

For getting video information you may can try following code.

```
fFmpeg.execute('-i video.mp4 -f null /dev/null').then((value) {
  print('Got value ');
}).catchError((error) {
  print('Error');
});
```

Comment: I have got a path to the video. I want to fetch metadata with the absolute path of the video.

Comment: Only video name is given in ffmpeg arguments in your code.

Comment: Where is your file?

Comment: When i trim with ffmpeg, the first few seconds, i get only the sound no video. After few seconds is when the video comes. What could be the issue.